# Git commit: Parse to necessary format

Tags: git, git-bash

I am using the Git bash to get the commit history on a git branch (using the tool for the first time). When I am using the `git log` command, I am getting the commits in the following format

```
1erdf146: 2020-06-15 (myself)  #Ticket Subject: Ticket I used to commit #Ticket ID: https://myjiralink.com/r-12345 #Ticket Summary: My Summary
```

Is there a way to extract the #Ticket Subject and #Ticket summary and commit date? I have to do it for each and every commit.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you mean by _extract_ the subject and summary? What is your desired output? How would you want to process it further?

Comment: When I say extract, I would like to apply the regex to get the pattern in this manner

#Ticket Subject: Ticket I used to commit   #Ticket ID: https://myjiralink.com/r-12345

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure your question is actually about `git` and not more about string parsing.

With `git log` you can customize the output format quite freely. For example you could only output the commit date and the commit subject:

```
git log --format=format:"%cs %s"
```

For more details see [the format section in the `git log` man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_pretty_formats).

To now extract the ticket subject/summary you need to parse/process the commit message, e.g. using [`grep` (1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep):

```
# output the commit dates
git log --format=format:"%cs"

# output only the Ticket Subject part of the commit message
git log --format=format:"%s" | grep -Po '(?<=#Ticket Subject: ).*?(?= *#Ticket|$)'

# output only the Ticket Summary part of the commit message
git log --format=format:"%s" | grep -Po '(?<=#Ticket Summary: ).*?(?= *#Ticket|$)'

# output only the Ticket ID part of the commit message
git log --format=format:"%s" | grep -Po '(?<=#Ticket ID: ).*?(?= *#Ticket|$)'
```

You may also want to have a look at [`sed` (1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed) and [`awk` (1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/awk) for more options on processing the output.